# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES): PhpMyAdmin

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, privileges

Given this code :

```
package db;

import java.sql.*;

public class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
    {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        String string = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb";

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(string , "root" , "root");
        PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("select * from name");
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
        while (result.next())
        {
            System.out.println(result.getString(1) + " " + result.getString(2));
        }


    }
}
```

I'm trying to connect mysql server but I get this :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4006)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:919)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1694)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1244)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2397)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2430)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2215)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:813)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:399)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:334)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at db.Main.main(Main.java:14)
```

Line `14` is that : `Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(string , "root" , "root");`

I'm sure that when I installed `MySql` I entered the password `root` . Just to make sure ,
I entered here : [image: to this] ,

and changed the password to `root` , like this : [image] , but I still can't get any correct output .

Any idea what's wrong with it ?

Thanks

**REMARK:**
Just to be clear , I'm using :

1. Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
2. Tomcat 7
3. Xampp

Comment: Are you able to open phpMyAdmin and run a query there? It seems that connection is not opened.

Comment: @imrantariq: Now I'm locked out of `phpMyAdmin` . I removed the lines as was suggested , and not it keeps me out `MySQL said: 

#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) `

Comment: It means you cannot open phpMyAdmin. Right?

Comment: @imrantariq: Yeap , but now I removed everything and re-installed `mysql` & `xampp` & `tomcat7` and I'm back in again . However , I still get the same output from mysql regarding connection from `java` & `jdbc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for
>   user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

You get this error when user has no rights to access localhost.

You need to grant access to root from localhost.

As you have added that. I doubt that problem lies with the row with `password='NO'` with `mySQL` settings.

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following commands with your username and password:

```
grant usage on *`.`* to `devuser@localhost` identified by '`devpassword`';
grant all privileges on `dev.` to `devuser@localhost`;
```

Comment: replace  star.star  is not displaying properly. So please use star.star immediately after ' grant usage on' instead of just dot

Answer (score -1):

Your problem has nothing to do with phpMyAdmin.its just an interface.

beside that, i think you should remove the rows with  password ="NO"

Comment: Are you sure about this ? because the last time I did that , the privileges of my account had been revoked .

Comment: well , on our server , there are 4 rows for root. all has password="YES" . including localhost and 127.0.0.1 . u can also remove the "ANY" rows.  And your code should be running on the same machine , or on a tunneled machine

Comment: ???? my answer is correct and same with the chosen answer.And im the first one to answer. yet i get a downvote?!!??!